# When hover too fast between elements, double elements show

Tags: jquery

When I hover between elements very quickly, two or more elements will show. If move slowly, it works perfect. Here's the code:

```
$("#services_menu a").hover(function(e) {
  var id = this.hash;
    $("#services_description div:visible").not(id).fadeOut('fast', function(){
    $(id).fadeIn();
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
$("#services_description div:not(#agency_leasing)").hide();
```

How do I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put

```
.stop(true,true)
```

before `fadeOut` and `fadeIn`